# How to find out if a user actually has Glass

Tags: google-mirror-api

I'm writing a fairly complicated application for Glass and I'm worried about users coming in, signing up, and using the resources for my AppEngine account even though they don't have Glass and will get no benefit from it. Is there currently any way in the Mirror API to actually determine if a user has Glass?

Comment: `will get no benefit from it` <- wouldn't this be the biggest deterrent from people falsely signing up?

Comment: Jason - Not really. They can still sign up for your app now in hopes that they'll get Glass shortly or sometime in the future. And in the meantime they're using up your (very limited) API courtesy limit.

Answer (score 4):

I think a way to verify they have Glass would be an excellent idea. This has been requested on the [issues list](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=107).

In the mean time, you might want to implement "double opt-in". It is considered best practice to send a "welcome" card - you might want to extend that welcome card to tell them to acknowledge the card. This can be a fairly simple operation, and it isn't burdensome to either them or you. If they don't within some reasonable time frame (or after some reminders... or whatever), then you can probably disable your Glass activities to them.

Actually... the more I think about it, the more I like this idea even once our API quota limits are lifted...